# Como faço para mostrar a notificação quando faltarem -30 dias para a data de expiração

Tags: php, html, symfony-2, twig

Tenho essa condição para mostrar a notificação quando a data de expiração estiver faltando 30 dias, mas não está fazendo o que eu quero. Alguém tem uma ideia melhor?

```
{% if entity.isExpired %}

          strong>Alerta!</strong>O produto com o código {{ entity.id }} esta com a data de validade vencida 

{% elseif entity.dataentrada == date(entity.isExpired)|date("-30 days") %}

          <strong>Alerta!</strong>  <a href="{{ path('armazem_showatual', { 'id': entity.id }) }}"> O produto com o código {{ entity.id }} esta com a pouco dias para fechar

                   {% endif %}
```

Comment: Eu não sei como o Entity funciona, mas você pode pegar a data atual `date('Y-m-d')`, converter a data do produto no banco de dados para o formato `AAAA-MM-DD` com o PHP `date_format('01-01-2016', 'Y-m-d')` e calcular a diferença entre elas.

Comment: Boa noite eduardo, o Entity.isExpired é a data de expiração que eu defino ao fazer cadastro de um produto. e o entity.dataentrada  é a data de cadastro, é ele pega apartir do banco de dados(Timestamp)..

Comment: Então, você só precisa calcular a diferença entre a data de expiração e a data atual em dias, não?!

Answer (score 2):

Código de exemplo:

```
<?php

$data_atual = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$data_expiracao = new DateTime('2016-10-01');

$intervalo_em_dias = $data_atual->diff($data_expiracao);

echo $intervalo_em_dias->format('%R%a dias');
```

Se for negativo o resultado, por exemplo, `-230`, quer dizer que já se passaram 230 dias da expiração. Se for positivo, por exemplo, `+27`, quer dizer que faltam 27 dias para expirar.

Answer (score 2):

Se o objeto possui um atributo com a data de entrada (no caso, `$dataentrada`), basta usá-lo para calcular se o objeto está expirado ou não:

```
/**
 * @return bool Se o objeto está expirado.
 */
public function isExpired()
{
    return $this->dataentrada->diff(new \DateTime())->d > 30;
}
```

(lembrando que o método `\DateTime::diff()` retorna um objeto do tipo `\DateInterval` cujo atributo `d` é a diferença em dias).

Comment: ele esta me retornado todos os produtos, mas eu só quero que ele me retorna os produtos com estão com menos de 30 dias para expirar

Comment: Pelo que você perguntou, você quer receber todos os produtos e exibir a notificação para aqueles que estão para expirar. Se você quer buscar apenas os produtos que estão para expirar, precisa criar um método no repositório de produtos para buscar aqueles que estão para expirar. Melhore sua pergunta.

Comment: Sim.eu que quero que ele me mostre apenas os produtos que estão com menos de 30 dias para expirar,consoante a aproximação da data de validade.

Comment: Como você busca os produtos, hoje?

Comment: Como eu tenho uma data de validade,entao eu digo para ele se if entity.isExpired entao mostra o id do prodruto elseif entity.isExpired|date('-30 days')  mostra o id do produto.  ou seja eu quero  que ele mostre apenas os que têm menos -30 para à data de validade